# MapStruct Multiple values in @BeanMapping(qualifiedByName)

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I have a mapper abstract class in which I have a function which is mapping entity from dto. I would like to use three different methods from this abstract class, each is in charge of mapping different things. Each of function is annotated with `@Named` and above main mapping function I put `@BeanMapping`. If i choose one of those three functions and I put it's name like this `@BeanMapiing(qualifiedByName = "x")` everything works fine but I'd like to use all of them by putting their names as an array like this `@BeanMapping(qualifiedByName = {"x","y","z"})` none of them is used in implemented method. Is there any way to make this work ? My code looks like this:

```
public abstract class EntityMapper{
 @BeanMapping(qualifiedByName = {"x","y","z"})
 public abstract Entity dtoToEntity(Dto dto);
 
 @Named("x")
 @AfterMapping
 public void methodX(Dto dto){
 //implementation
 }

 @Named("y")
 @AfterMapping
 public void methodY(Dto dto){
 //implementation
 }

 @Named("z")
 @AfterMapping
 public void methodZ(Dto dto){
 //implementation
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no support to pick multiple different `@Named` methods that would be picked up. When using multiple methods in `BeanMapping#qualifiedByName` then you need to have all of them available, either on the class or the method.

I would advise looking into nested qualifiers, by moving your methods in different class / interface and then annotating that one.

e.g.

```
@Named("classLevel")
public class Utils {

    @Named("methodLevel")
    @AfterMapping
    public void methodX(Dto dto){
        //implementation
    }

    @Named("methodLevel")
    @AfterMapping
    public void methodY(Dto dto){
        //implementation
    }

    @Named("methodLevel")
    @AfterMapping
    public void methodZ(Dto dto){
        //implementation
    }
}
```

And then

```
@BeanMapping(qualifiedByName = {"classLevel", "methodLevel"})
```